# Using an omen card, can you kill yourself?

Tags: betrayal-at-house-on-the-hill

Let's say I have Sanity 3, the last Sanity step on my character sheet, and I choose to use the omen card Mask. I roll a 4+, which means I can put on the mask to gain 2 Knowledge and lose 2 Sanity. Did I just kill myself when I have only one Sanity step left? Does my Sanity level drop to a minimum? Or does it drop to 0, killing me? Can I decide after rolling 4+ that I don't want to use the mask?

Comment: Why would you ever bother rolling if you know that you would choose to not use the mask even if you succeed?

Comment: I checked my characters sanity only after doing the roll.

Comment: Fair enough. I know for sure any group of people I'd be likely to play with would have no issue just letting you ignore the roll if you explained that you didn't notice that your sanity was that low, even if the rules didn't technically allow you to ignore it because of the "can" wording.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text on the Mask omen 4+ roll reads "You can put on or take off the mask.", keyword here I think being "can". If you attempt the roll and get the 4+, read as written you can choose not to put the mask on.

That being said, if losing 2 sanity would cause you to go lower than the lowest sanity level on your character, yes, putting the mask on would cause your character to "go insane" and your character would die and drop the Mask.

The one stipulation to this being that your character cannot die before the haunt has begun, so this only applies post-haunt beginning. That rule is on page 8 under "Making an Attack".

Comment: Thank you! Yes the word can gives there a lot of meaning. If there would be must, I would have to take on or off the mask. Here I can put on or of the mask but I dont need to do anything with it if I choose to.  :)

Comment: Betrayal is notorious for loose & inconsistent wording. It says "can put on or take off the mask" - I read it as you have the option to either put it on or take it off, depending on whether it is currently on or not. If you don't want the mask on, you just don't make roll.

Comment: @KenHerbert, Definitely true. I love the game to death but a lot of the rules come down to personal interpretation, in this case it being whether the emphasis is on the word "can" or the word "or".  Either way you're right, you should just avoid the roll all together if succeeding will kill you, since a 0-3 has no effect at all.

Comment: I checked my characters sanity only after doing the roll.

Comment: I think an important part of this answer is the part about the haunt having started or not.